# What is the difference between trend and adjusted on seasonal?

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, time-series

I tried the "example usage" of seasonal https://github.com/welch/seasonal. Code is as below.

```
import math
from seasonal import fit_seasons,adjust_seasons
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

s = [10 * math.sin(i * 2 * math.pi / 25) + i * i /100.0 for i in range(100)]
seasons,trend = fit_seasons(s)

adjusted = adjust_seasons(s,seasons=seasons)

residual = adjusted -trend
```

What the differance between adjusted and trend?

Answer (score 0):

This is the "seasonally adjusted" data; i.e. the data with the seasonal component extracted. If the signal is `Y` and the decomposition is written as `Y = S + T + R` where `S` is the seasonal component, `T` is the trend, and `R` is the residual, then the "seasonally adjusted" result is just `T + R`.